# AngularJS: same logic but different HTML forms & database for different projects/clients

Tags: angularjs, configuration

The app which I am developing will have the same functionality for all users/clients/projects (call 'em what you will).

However, the HTML forms presented to the user and the AJAX used to send them to the server will vary for each project.

I was thinking of using [Angular constants](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide), with `ng-show` / `ng-hide` (maybe even `ng-if`) on the HTML and a switch in the controller, based on a constant for the AJAX send & receive.

Is this a good approach? I can see things getting complex with more than a handful of projects. Should I use a different view/controller for each project? I might lose out on some common code that way, but it's less likely t become spaghetti.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest taking a *domain/(test)* driven approach. Don't *generalize* too much code up front.

Building generalized code will create dependencies that are all a potential victim in need of future refactoring. Even in the case of simple changes. Nothing is more time consuming / frustrating than those small modifications that cause an avalanche. I've seen alot of projects run out of time because the code base was over engineered at the start.

My approach, especially for the more complex projects with no clear overview of overlapping functionalities, is to just start designing/building the functionalities separate of each other in small steps. Just like any *agile* workflow, deliver a complete working feature (a working form) and when you're working on feature and notice that there's a shared functionality build earlier on, make a (wise) decision to refactor/promote the existing code into generalized code. At this stage you'll be in a better position to make such a judgement. If you've taken the test driven approach (which I highly recommend) refactoring the existing code can be done without too much effort.

Working this way gives a greater guarantee to deliver and to end up with good readable optimised code.

## TL;DR

It all comes down to common sense.